# Compare columns in two csv files and write it to another file in python

Tags: python, csv

I have two csv files.

File 1 with filepath,group,permission like below

```
/path/eds/aws/file1.dat,dp_card,640                                                       
/path/eds/aws/file2.dat,dp_card,600     
/path/edh/vs/file1.dat,dp_card,640    
/pth/edw/de/file1.dat,pdp_card,640      
/pth/edn/de/file1.dat,pdp_card,640
```

File 2 with directory path,group,batch owner like below

```
/path/eds/aws/,dp_card,dp_batchown    
/path/edh/vs/,dp_card,dp_batchown   
/path/edw/de/,pdp_card,dp_batchown
```

I want to compare two files based on the path present in the file2. If the path is present in file 1 i want to write filename,group,permission,path,group to another file.

the sample output:

File 3

```
/path/eds/aws/file1.dat,dp_card,640,/path/eds/aws/,dp_card
/path/eds/aws/file2.dat,dp_card,600,/path/eds/aws/,dp_card
/path/edh/vs/file1.dat,dp_card,640,/path/edh/vs/,dp_card
/pth/edw/de/file1.dat,pdp_card,640,/path/edw/de/,dp_card
```

can some one please help me in writing code for the above. I was trying it from yesterday.

Code i have written so far.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import csv
import os.path

csv_dialect = dict(delimiter=',', quotechar='|')

path = set()
with open('hdfs','rb') as file_a : 
    reader1 = csv.reader(file_a, **csv_dialect)
    next(reader1)
    for row in reader1:
      dirpath = os.path.dirname(row[0])
      #absp = abspath[:-1]
      path.add(dirpath)
      #print(abspath)

with open('file2', 'ab') as file_c:
    writer = csv.writer(file_c, **csv_dialect)
    with open('lake.csv', 'rb') as file_b:    
        reader2 = csv.reader(file_b, **csv_dialect)
        next(reader2)
        for row in reader2: 
            dirpath1 = os.path.dirname(row[0])
            #print(dirpath1)
            if (dirpath1) in path:
                writer.writerow(row)
                #print(row)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Nobody wants to create a full solution for you. Demonstrate that you've made some effort to solve the issue.

Comment: You might consider using the [pandas module](http://pandas.pydata.org/) for this task.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas makes this very easy and also highly readable

```
import pandas as pd
import os.path

df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.txt', header=None, names=['fpath', 'group', 'permission'])
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.txt', header=None, names=['dpath', 'group', 'owner'])
df1['dpath'] = df1['fpath'].apply(os.path.dirname)
df2['dpath'] = df2['dpath'].apply(os.path.dirname)
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on="dpath", how="inner")
df3[['fpath', 'group_x', 'permission', 'dpath', 'group_y']].to_csv(
    'file3.txt', index=False, header=False)
```

Output file3.txt:

```
/path/eds/aws/file1.dat,dp_card,640,/path/eds/aws,dp_card
/path/eds/aws/file2.dat,dp_card,600,/path/eds/aws,dp_card
/path/edh/vs/file1.dat,dp_card,640,/path/edh/vs,dp_card
```